# Include unmatched rows in Python script that merges two files based on one column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two csv files shown below.

First file:

> abTestGroup,platform,countryCode,userId
>
> group_control,ios,GB,aaaaaaaaaaa group_control,ios,GB,aaaaaaaaaaa
>
> group_control,ios,GB,aaaaaaaaaaa group_control,ios,GB,aaaaaaaaaaa
>
> group_test,android,GB,ccccccccccc

Second file:

> dateActivity,productId,cost,userId
>
> 2018-03-02,specialpack,0.198,aaaaaaaaaaa
>
> 2018-03-03,specialpack,0.498,aaaaaaaaaaa
>
> 2018-03-02,specialpack,0.398,bbbbbbbbbbb
>
> 2018-03-02,specialpack,0.998,ccccccccccc

and they have one common thing in this case which is the `userId`.

I want to merge those files and create a parent-child relationship using Python (Pandas).

I have used the script below:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('PARENT.csv', encoding = "UTF-8", mangle_dupe_cols=True, usecols=['abTestGroup','platform','countryCode','userId'])
b = pd.read_csv("CHILD.csv")
merged = b.merge(a, on='userId', how='inner')

merged = merged.drop_duplicates()

merged.to_csv("final_output.csv", index=False)
```

in order to get the following output:

> dateActivity,productId,cost,userId,abTestGroup,platform,countryCode
>
> 2018-03-02,specialpack,0.198,aaaaaaaaaaa,group_control,ios,GB
>
> 2018-03-03,specialpack,0.498,aaaaaaaaaaa,group_control,ios,GB
>
> 2018-03-02,specialpack,0.998,ccccccccccc,group_test,android,GB

The `userId` *'bbbbbbbbbbb'* does not appear in the final output because it doesn't exist in both files. How can I include the unmatched rows (unmatched `userIds`) and assign the 'Other' value to the cells?

Comment: see this on [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing an inner join, only the matched `userIds` will be return. In order to return unmatched `userIds`, you can do a right/left join depending on the sequence of join in the following  statement.

```
merged = b.merge(a, on='userId', how='inner')
```

If `b` contains `bbbbbbbbbbb` you would do a left join. If `a` contains `bbbbbbbbbbb` then you would do a right join.

```
merged = b.merge(a, on='userId', how='left')
merged = b.merge(a, on='userId', how='right')
```

Please see the join types below.

[image: The difference between joins]

Comment: Yes. I skipped that. I should take more breaks :P SQL was the basic knowledge needed here.

Answer (score 0):

join method will work for your case:

```
a.join(b)
```